# Trello Manatee - How to filter cards in a list by Date (since and before)

Tags: manatee.trello

I want to fetch cards by date, for example:

```
list.Cards.Filter(CardFilter.Closed).Since("someDate").toList()
```

but there is no extension for cards like actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>There is a `Filter ()` overload that takes start and end dates.</strike>

### Edit 1

This is wrong.  I was thinking action collections.  I'll check the API and come back.

### Edit 2

As per the [Trello docs](https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/list#get-1-lists-idlist-cards-filter) there is no "get cards by date" function.  However, there are a couple ways to do this:

- By creation date

  list.Cards.Filter(CardFilter.Closed)
            .Where(c => c.CreationDate >= someDate);
- By last modified date

  list.Cards.Filter(CardFilter.Closed)
            .Where(c => c.LastActivity >= someDate);

Also, remember that you can get cards for lists (as you're doing and above) as well as all of the cards for an entire board.

### Edit 3

Manatee.Trello v1.16.0 provides this functionality as a new overload of the `Filter()` extension method on the `ReadOnlyCardCollection` object.  You can use it like this:

```
list.Cards.Filter(new DateTime(2017,1,1), null);
```

to get all cards in a list that were created after 1 Jan 2017.  The other parameter is an end date.

Comment: But in API document there is an argument named Since. you can see in this link: https://developers.trello.com/advanced-reference/board#get-1-boards-board-id-cards

Comment: the link is not working very well, I mean this method: GET /1/boards/[board_id]/cards

Comment: I'll have to research that and find out what it does (how it filters).  Thanks for pointing that out.  I should be able to work it in, but I want to be clear what those dates mean (created, edited, etc.).

Comment: From what I can tell, it's a created date.  I've created an [issue](https://github.com/gregsdennis/Manatee.Trello/issues/64) in my repo.  You can track progress there.  Until that's ready, please use the workaround shown above.